power automate http action for powerbi rest api
I tried to get token for powerbi rest api using http in power automation:
In the “URI” field, I enter the following: https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenantid/oauth2/token
In the “Headers” section, add the following key-value pair:
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:
grant_type=client_credentials&username=xxx&password=xxx
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
Have error:
'client_assertion', 'client_secret' or 'request' is required for the 'client_credentials' grant type.
I need to enter that without client_id and client_secret. What is request in this case? What is body looks like without client_id and client_secret?
Thanks
